# Angular 6 do I have to generate jwt in client to match server or just the server

Tags: angular, jwt, angular6

I am a total newbie to jwt and I thank you for your patience.

I am generating jwt in PHP with the following:

```
// Create token header as a JSON string
$header = json_encode(['typ' => 'JWT', 'alg' => 'HS256']);

// Create token payload as a JSON string
$payload = json_encode(['username' => $this->username, 'password' => $this->password]);

// Encode Header to Base64Url String
$base64UrlHeader = str_replace(['+', '/', '='], ['-', '_', ''], base64_encode($header));

// Encode Payload to Base64Url String
$base64UrlPayload = str_replace(['+', '/', '='], ['-', '_', ''], base64_encode($payload));

// Create Signature Hash
$signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $base64UrlHeader . "." . $base64UrlPayload, '<big secret>', true);

// Encode Signature to Base64Url String
$base64UrlSignature = str_replace(['+', '/', '='], ['-', '_', ''], base64_encode($signature));
```

All of that was just to generate the signature - $base64UrlSignature - which is then set to the key:

$this->key = $base64UrlSignature;

```
        $token = array(
            "iss" => $this->iss,
            "aud" => $this->aud,
            "iat" => $this->iat,
            "nbf" => $this->nbf,
            "data" => array(
                "username" => $this->username,
                "password" => $this->password
                )
        );

        // generate jwt
        $this->jwt = JWT::encode($token, $this->key);
        echo json_encode(
            array(
                "status" => 401,
                "id" => 0,
                "uName" => "Guest",
                "isAdmin" => "0",
                "ts" => "2018-12-28 00:00:00",
                "loggedIn" => false,
                "msg" => "Combination of username and password not found",
                "jwt" => $this->jwt
            )
        );
```

My question is, do I have to do the same on the client side in Angular, to see if it matches with the one generated by the server?

So far all that I have read, has to do with the server generating the jwt, then in Angular do the following:

```
localStorage.setItem("jwt", res.jwt);
```

Just place in local storage. Is that all there is to it?

Shouldn't there be a comparison of the token generated by the server to the token generated by the client?

If so, then how do I translate the above code to do so? For instance, what is the equivalent in Angular to Google's jwt PHP class:

```
$this->jwt = JWT::encode($token, $this->key);
```

I am adding code to the original post. The following is the interceptor that I have made:

```
import { ShoppingCartValuesService } from "./shopping-cart-values.service";
import { Injectable, Injector } from "@angular/core";
import {
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpRequest
} from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/";
import * as jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(public srvc: ShoppingCartValuesService) {}
  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const idToken = localStorage.getItem("jwt");

    if (idToken) {
      const cloned = req.clone({
        headers: req.headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + idToken)
      });
      console.log("Decoded jwt token: ", this.getDecodedAccessToken(idToken));
      return next.handle(cloned);
    } else {
      return next.handle(req);
    }
  }

  getDecodedAccessToken(token: string): any {
    try {
      return jwt_decode(token);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error: ", error);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Which is called anytime a click is made in the links of the navbar via the click handler checkRequest() that is passed the route and later prepends the entire URL:

```
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a
      class="nav-link"
      data-toggle="tooltip"
      title="Products"
      routerLink="/products"
      id="products"
      (click)="checkRequest('/products')"
      ><span>Products</span></a
    >
  </li>
```

Modifying post once again to show console.log result from the (click)="checkRequest('/products');

CheckRequest method:

```
checkRequest(url) {
const newUrl = this.srvc.serverBase + url;
this.clickResponse = this.http.get(newUrl, { observe: "body" });
console.log(
  "newUrl: " +
    newUrl +
    " this.clickResponse: " +
    JSON.stringify(this.clickResponse)
);
```

}

From console.log when clicking the '/products' link:

```
newUrl: http://local.kronus:8001/products this.clickResponse: {"_isScalar":false,"source":{"_isScalar":false,"source":{"_isScalar":false,"source":{"_isScalar":true,"value":{"url":"http://local.kronus:8001/products","body":null,"reportProgress":false,"withCredentials":false,"responseType":"json","method":"GET","headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"params":{"updates":null,"cloneFrom":null,"encoder":{},"map":null},"urlWithParams":"http://local.kronus:8001/products"}},"operator":{"concurrent":1}},"operator":{}},"operator":{}}
```

The interceptor does not seem to be producing anything. Is there something that I missing to include the interceptor somehow?

Another update: after some more reading, I realized that I need to inject the interceptor into my login service:

```
private authInt: AuthInterceptor
```

Also, I added to the login service:

```
clickResponse: Observable<any>;
```

I moved the checkRequest method to the login service:

```
checkRequest(url) {
  const newUrl = this.appBase + url;
  return (this.clickResponse = this.http.get(newUrl, { observe: "body" }));
}
```

In the navbar component, I changed the method to the following calling the service's checkRequest:

```
checkRequest(url) {
this.srvc.checkRequest(url).subscribe(data => {
  console.log("after clicking login: ", data);
});
}
```

Here is the 404 error in the console:

```
    HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://localhost:4200/login", ok: false, …}
error: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang="en">↵<head>↵<meta charset="utf-8">↵<title>Error</title>↵</head>↵<body>↵<pre>Cannot GET /login</pre>↵</body>↵</html>↵"
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/login: 404 Not Found"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 404
statusText: "Not Found"
url: "http://localhost:4200/login"
```

How is it possible that /login is not found? I am literally on the login page. Is it because this checked before the app made the login page?

This is when I realized that I do not need to send '/login' but the uri to the api, which produced no errors, but no jwt in the headers either. I tried to do the same thing on admin/products page, which the following line seems to just return the payload coming from the api:

```
return (this.clickResponse = this.http.get(newUrl, { observe: "body" }));
```

Yet, I do not see anything in the headers section that jwt Authorization Bearer is passed. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Here is an excellent article from Angular University: [Angular Security - Authentication With JSON Web Tokens (JWT): The Complete Guide](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-jwt-authentication/).  It discusses several different strategies you can use with your Angular app.  You may save your token to localStorage; you can also use cookies.  You *must* use the token the server generates in subsequent communications between your app and the server.

Comment: @paulsm4 thank you for replying. I will read the article and thank you once more

Comment: And to answer your other question: it isn't necessary for the client to "validate" the JWT.  It's also worth mentioning that using HTTP (communicating in clear text) pretty much defeats the point of using a token in the first place.  You should use JWT tokens in conjunction with HTTPS transport.

Comment: @paulsm4 thank you for replying. Is there something in my code that makes you think that it is going to be on an HTTPS domain/web site? Is it the echo of json_encoded array? If so, then what else can I do for the subscribe(result => { this.jwtObj = result }) to receive the response in my Angular 6 app that is posting the request?

Comment: No, I'm saying your server *should* be an HTTPS web site.  Otherwise, the token can be easily hijacked.  In which case - what's the point of using a token?  There's actually a strong argument that *ALL* Internet-facing sites should be HTTPS.  For example: https://www.theverge.com/2018/2/8/16991254/chrome-not-secure-marked-http-encryption-ssl

Comment: Hey @paulsm4, thank you for replying and I have updated the code with an interceptor, but I am not seeing anything in the headers. Can you tell me what I might be missing?

Comment: By "not seeing anything", I assume you mean: 1) Your interceptor *should* be writing the token, 2) You're checking a request in Chrome Developer Tools (or equivalent), 3) You see the HTTP headers ... but your token isn't among them, and 4) The server is saying "Error: token missing!" (or equivalent).  Correct?

Comment: I'd also add `console.log('AuthInterceptor::intercept()', req, next, idToken);` immediately after `localStorage.getItem()`.  Please verify: 1) the above modification, 2) your existing `console.log("Decoded jwt token:..)` also prints, 3) You've verified in Developer Tools (or equivalent) the HTTP header with the token is *NOT* present.

Comment: @paulsm4 - Yes, I thought that headers should show something like "Authorization", "Bearer " + idToken but I did not see anything in Chrome's dev tools. I did not see any server error. Editing post to show the result of console.log from any click - I was hoping to see jwt, but nothing instead

Comment: Q: Is there something that I missing to include the interceptor somehow?  A: Maybe.   If you're using the interceptor from a service, then you need to 1) register it with `useClass: myInterceptor` when you register the service in `providers[]` in  app.module.ts, 2) You then need to inject the interceptor into your service's constructor.  Here's a good link: https://ryanchenkie.com/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors

Comment: Thank you @paulsm4, I just discovered that I need to inject the interceptor into my login service and, as a result, I coming to update the post with the 404 error that I am receiving

Comment: Sorry @paulsm4, one more update. I do not need to send it '/login' I needed to send api url, but I am still not see any jwt in the headers. I see it in the response from the server. I guess this is because when I am logging in, I do not have a local storage yet, for the interceptor to read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following import into app.module.ts is what I was missing:

```
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from "@angular/common/http";
import { AuthInterceptor } from "./auth-interceptor";

{
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: AuthInterceptor,
  multi: true
}
```

Having HTTP_INTERCEPTORS in the providers array and using the auth interceptor that I made, automatically attaches to every http request - EVERY http request.

Also, at times I tried to inject the auth interceptor into the login services, when I eventually realized that I needed to inject the services into my interceptor, with the following call to this.srvc.getToken():

```
if (idToken) {
  const cloned = req.clone({
    headers: req.headers.set(
      "Authorization",
      "Bearer " + this.srvc.getToken()
    )
  });
  // console.log("Decoded jwt token: ", this.getDecodedAccessToken(idToken));
  return next.handle(cloned);
} else {
  return next.handle(req);
}
```

getToken from service:

```
public getToken(): string {
  return localStorage.getItem("jwt");
}
```

Now my Request Headers look like the following:

```
Provisional headers are shown
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NDIwMCIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo0MjAwIiwiaWF0IjoxNTQ2OTU5NzUzLCJuYmYiOjE1NDY5NTg3NTMsImRhdGEiOnsibmFtZSI6InRhbUBrcm9udXNwcm9kdWN0aW9ucy5jb20iLCJwYXNzMSI6ImVhYmNkMTIzNDUifX0.GF1kFxdMe3Jd_paxu89Dve23ysguz4LGxXmGIDOz9Yc
Content-Type: application/json
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/login
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
```

Since these tests are on my dev environment, then I do not to be running on https, but @paulsm4 is correct that all this needs to be done over https

BTW, thanks for your patience as I asked several questions

Comment: Cool - glad you got it working!  Be sure to "accept" your solution.